# Dual Monitor or Multi-Monitor Not Working When I switched Wayland to X11

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, display, hdmi

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3

I have two monitors both are connected with HDMI. The primary one is with the motherboard's HDMI and the other/secondary one is with Intel Arc A750 GPU HDMI port.

Both monitors work as expected. The Upwork desktop app can not take screenshots because of the **Wayland** windowing system. It is recommended to use Xorg.

I just followed the following steps to switch Wayland to X11:

1. Run the Terminal app, and enter the command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

2. Uncomment the line to disable Wayland by removing the # sign:

WaylandEnable=false‍

3. Finally, restart GDM:

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm3
```

When I logged in, the secondary monitor was not on screen(no signal).

I switched back to Wayland and working fine. Could you give me a solution so that apps like Upwork can take screenshots as well as both monitors run perfectly?